# custom logging in expressjs 3.x

Tags: express

How do I log into a log file instead of calling the console.log. I checked this
[Logging in express js to a output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489815/logging-in-express-js-to-a-output-file)
but this would only log the request/response to the file. How would I log my error/info msg into the log directory(custom Logging).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`log4js-node`](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) or [`winston`](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) modules for logging in node.js.

Comment: thanks. I think we can use winston as well..I just wanted to see which one would more supported and being used by all. thanks again

Comment: @coool Good point about winston as that's another good option.  Added.

Comment: + for log4js-node - i've found it the easiest way to connect this logger with expressjs.