# How to actually separate access log from error log in Node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I've seen this question:
[Logging in express js to a output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489815/logging-in-express-js-to-a-output-file)

But after reading documentation on `logger` middleware, still not sure how you can actually separate access log from error log, so that access log contains only url access data, and error log contains only errors.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in connect logger is dedicated to a single purpose: logging the basic details about incoming HTTP requests. You can control the exact format of the log messages with the configuration parameters, but fundamentally that middleware is for logging requests a la access.log. To log errors and have them go to a separate file, you'll need to write an error handling middleware with a signature of `(error, req, res, next)`. You can wire that up with `app.use` and write your errors to a file or just `stderr` as you wish. To trigger it from your normal routes or middleware, just pass an `Error` instance to the `next(error)` callback.

Comment: Okay, so if I understood you correctly, something like what I want does not exist yet, so I'll have to write it myself. Thanks, will try.

Comment: It may, but I didn't search google/npm for you. We're talking about ~20 lines of code max in a single function. Shouldn't be a big deal to write.