# Built in access logs in node.js (express framework)

Tags: node.js, logging, express, access-log

I was wondering if **node.js** (or **express** framework) has any kind of built in access logging like grails has for example?

I have grails application that runs on tomcat and it automatically generates `/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/logs/localhost_access_log.2013.10.30.txt` file in which are logs about request response like this one:

```
[30/Oct/2013:00:00:01 +0000] [my-ip-address] [http-bio-8080-exec-18] "GET /my-service/check HTTP/1.0" [200] [took: 1 milis]
```

This logs are written automatically by system and I don't have to worry about that.

So what about **node.js**?

Thanks for any help!

Ivan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging in express js to a output file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489815/logging-in-express-js-to-a-output-file)

Comment: It does. You have to enable it. See the answers to the question posted by thgaskell.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In newer versions of Express (**4.0.0** at the time of writing), the logger is no longer part of Express, so you have to include it as a dependency manually. It is now called [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).

So, in `package.json`, add morgan as a dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "morgan": "*"
  ...
}
```

And in your Express configuration, add:

```
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
```

Now logging should work more or less like before. :-)

Comment: We have to use new versions of Express.

Comment: @Dalinaum Then this is for you. :-)

Answer (score 13):

As of now, most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with express and must be installed separately.

Short answer:
First, install `morgan`:

```
npm install morgan
```

Then use it for logging:

```
app = express();
var morgan  = require('morgan')
...
app.use(morgan('combined'))
```

Documentation is **[here](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)**.

Answer (score 10):

**edit** As of express `4.0.0` this solution is apparently no longer enough. Check out the answer from whirlwin for an updated solution.

You can use `app.use(express.logger());`

Documented here: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to add execution time to it like in my grails logger?

Comment: @ivan_zd `:response-time`

Comment: Well, according to the documentation on the link, the first paramater to logger() is the format. And they cover formatting options further down on the page. I don't use the logger though so I don't know from the top of my head...

Answer (score 2):

It's not built in but really easy to configure. You can use [express-winston](https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston/blob/master/Readme.md) and add to the express middleware stack. `morgan` [does not let you log the request body](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/32) but expressWinston does:

```
expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body');
expressWinston.responseWhitelist.push('body');
```

Example in coffeescript:

```
expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body')
expressWinston.responseWhitelist.push('body')
app.use(expressWinston.logger({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
          json: true,
          colorize: true
        })
      ],
      meta: true, // optional: control whether you want to log the meta data about the request (default to true)
      msg: "HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}}", // optional: customize the default logging message. E.g. "{{res.statusCode}} {{req.method}} {{res.responseTime}}ms {{req.url}}"
      expressFormat: true, // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting, with the same colors. Enabling this will override any msg and colorStatus if true. Will only output colors on transports with colorize set to true
      colorStatus: true, // Color the status code, using the Express/morgan color palette (default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red). Will not be recognized if expressFormat is true
      ignoreRoute: function (req, res) { return false; } // optional: allows to skip some log messages based on request and/or response
    }));
```

Comment: instead of this shouldn't i use winston only ??