# How to write console.log to a file instead

Tags: javascript, node.js

Now I show the information using:

```
console.log (kraken.id, markets)
```

However, I want to write all the information that goes to the console to a file instead. How can that be done by completing the below code?

```
'use strict';
var ccxt = require('ccxt');

(async () => {
  let kraken = new ccxt.kraken()
  let markets = await kraken.load_markets()
  //console.log (kraken.id, markets)


  //How to write above console.log to file?
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile("/Users/Andreas/Desktop/NODE/myproject/files/test.txt", "allinfoAsstring", function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
  });
})()
```

Comment: easiest solution would be running it, so it would pipe to the file `node yourscript.js > file.log 2>&1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node: log in a file instead of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try to create an Object out of your variables and format them as a JSON string.

```js
/* ... */
const obj = {kraken, markets}

const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/Users/Andreas/Desktop/NODE/myproject/files/test.txt", JSON.stringify(obj), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Later, you can retrieve the values from the file, by running

```js
fs.readFile('/Users/Andreas/Desktop/NODE/myproject/files/test.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
 const obj = JSON.parse(data)

 console.log("The data from the file is: " + obj)
})
```

Comment: That was great. This worked out very well! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 15):

thx for the diverse solutions.  the simplest way for me was

`node app.js > app.log 2>&1`

This would redirect stdout to a file named app.log and redirect stderr to stdout.

So all my `console.log` are going to `app.log`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify(obj)`, every object can be convert into string via this method.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using console.log in production as it sync code.
you can use [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) instead

and you got in an easy way all the logs to file (if you wanted) by using new transports

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
  transports: [
    //
    // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
    // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
    //
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
  ]
});
```

Comment: What did you mean "as it sync code"? That console.log is blocking whereas winston logger is not?

Comment: @samlaf yes, exactly! `console.log` blocks the main thread while running (for example when printing out huge objects) while (apparently) winston does not.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to loicnestler's answer that means you don't need to change your 'console.log' statements:

Update the reference to 'console.log', so it calls 'writeFile' when logging:

```
const log = console.log;
console.log = (data) => {
    log(data);
    <loicnestler's writeFile logic>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Node, `console.log()` calls [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to print objects.

You should call that directly and write it to a file.

Comment: I am a bit new to node.js so I am not sure how to do this exactly. Is it possible to show some code how I can do that with reference to my code snippet to have a good example?

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking how to call a function? How to write to a file? Did you read the documentation?